# Accessing a base class variable inaccessible error

Tags: c#

I have a basic class setup of Items that receive some damage and have a health status. But for some reason i cannot access the base variables as i get inaccessible error.

This is my code setup:

```
public abstract class Items
{

    public float health { get; private set; }
    public Items()
    {
        health = 100f;
    }
}

public class Sword : Items
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public float maxPower { get; private set; }

    public Sword(string n float mPower) : base()
    {
        name  = n;
        maxPower = mPower;

    }

    public void UpdateDamage(float damageAmount)
    {
        health = Mathf.Clamp(health - damageAmount,0,100);
    }
}
```

The error is:

> 'Items.health' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I presumed because i set it to public i could access it in my damage method, but i guess not. Where did i go wrong here?

Comment: @Dabe - I'd also recommend reading here about [c# naming convensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the setter of the `Items` from `private` to `protected`. Because it is a `private set` only that class can set it an non other, even not the derived classes.

- To enable the derived classes to set it change to `protected set` (like below).
- To enable anyone to set it (`public`) remove the word and leave only `set;` - the default is `public`

For more information about the `access modifiers` of properties [check MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx#Anchor_2)

So:

```
public abstract class Items
{
    public float health { get; protected set; }
    public Items()
    {
        health = 100f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so what does protected mean ? I assumed protected meant it could not be changed.

Comment: @Dave - Just added some explanation

Comment: Thanks, just wondering also - what is better practice - my current setup, or use a virtual/override and call a base.UpdateDamage() whilst keeping health a private set?

Comment: @Dave - _My following comment is opinion based_ - I personally always leave the getters and setters `public` unless I feel that it is for sure only that class's responsibility to set them (usually due to some other internal logic of the class. _But again, this is opinion based_ :)